# Python заменить выражение в строке если оставшиеся части строки равны

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-2.x

Нужно заменить id из content2 (это `TU7D2IH8P2D001`) на id из content1 (`TYA1G2C9HMD001`) только в том случае если остальная часть выражения одинаковая. То есть в итоге нулевые элементы двух массивов должны стать равными, а первые остаться как есть.
У меня есть следующий код:

```
import re
content1 = ['MY SECRET CODE IS TYA1G2C9HMD001(\n YEAH IT IS EASY!\n', "HIS SECRET CODE IS  TU2Z3D43D4D002(\n  THIS IS DIFFERENT PART\n"]
content2 = ['MY SECRET CODE IS TU7D2IH8P2D001(\n YEAH IT IS EASY!\n', "HIS SECRET CODE IS  TU2A3C83D4D002(\n  THIS IS DIFFERENT PARTS\n"]
pattern = re.compile("^(.)*T[A-Z0-9]{10}[0-9]{3}[(](.)*$")
for c1, c2 in zip(content1, content2):
    # как-то сравнить id из c1 и с2 здесь
```

Я понимаю что это надо как-то делать при помощи re.sub, но я не понимаю как именно добавить проверку на равенство остальной строки. Версия python - 2.7. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может ли в одном элементе списка находиться более одного `id`?

Comment: В одном элементе списка может быть только один id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот примитивное решение "в лоб":

```
pattern = r'\b(T[A-Z0-9]{10}[0-9]{3})\b'
for i,_ in enumerate(content1):
    m = re.search(pattern, content1[i])
    if m.group(0):
        content2[i] = re.sub(pattern, m.group(0), content2[i])
```

Результат:

```
In [52]: content2
Out[52]:
['MY SECRET CODE IS TYA1G2C9HMD001(\n YEAH IT IS EASY!\n',
 'HIS SECRET CODE IS  TU2Z3D43D4D002(\n  THIS IS DIFFERENT PARTS\n']
```

Проверка:

```
In [54]: [c1==c2 for c1, c2 in zip(content1, content2)]
Out[54]: [True, False]
```